# Your profile cannot be used because it is from a newer version of NW.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, node-webkit, nwjs

Searching for this error text I get only info about Google Chrome.

I want to disable this warning or understand why this is happening.

I found this: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/5761 and deleted

```
~/Library/Application Support/nwjs/rm -rf Default/Web\ Data
~/Library/Application Support/nwjs/rm -rf Default/Web\ Data-journal
```

But when I run my app again, the error happens

[image]

This Message says:

> Your profile can not be used because it is from a newer version of NW.js
>
> Some features may be unavailable. Please specify a different profile directory or use a newer version of NW.js

I was using the latest verison of nw.js and switched to 0.23.7 for compatibility with https://github.com/greenheartgames/greenworks/releases .

How do I disable this error message? I'm concerned about users seeing this message.

Answer (score 1):

`rm -rf ~/Application\ Support/MyAppName`

and run again